# Identify and eliminate a stubborn white line

Tags: video, vertical-alignment

I am trying to eliminate a white line just under the homepage video of [this site](https://j4.nautilusitalia.com) . Can some css magician help me?
Thank you
Alberto

I eliminated all paddings and margins from the various containers, but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the origin of the white line: it was an unwanted

paragraph around the  tag added by the JCE editor!
As simple as that.
Sorry for raising this issue.
Alberto